# Sum of random number of random variables

Tags: probability

Consider a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ such that
$$
\mathbb P(X_i\geqslant k)=\prod_{\ell=1}^{k-2}\frac{n-\ell}n
\ \textrm{ for every } 2\leqslant k\leqslant n+1.
$$

Consider also
$$Z= \sum_{i=1}^Y X_i ,$$

where $Y$ follows a geometric distribution with success probability $1/n$.

What is the mean and variance of $Z$ and is it possible to calculate its full distribution?  I am particularly interested in what happens for large $n$.

Comment: If $Y,X_1,X_2,\ldots$ are independent, then $E(Z)$ is just equal to $E(Y)E(X)$. Otherwise, you need to specify how $Y,X_1,X_2,\ldots$ are related to each other.

Comment: Thanks. I should have added variance explicitly and not have it hidden in the full distribution part. Fixed.

Comment: But you haven't answer the key question: are $Y,X_1,X_2,\ldots$ ***independent***?

Comment: Sorry. Yes they are.

Comment: I have edited that bit of information into your question. See if I understand you correctly. If not, feel free to roll back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on @user1551 comment, under independence, you could use the law of iterated expectations to derive what you need.
First, the conditional expectation of $Z$ on fixing $Y=y$ is
\begin{eqnarray*}
  E \left[ Z|Y = y \right] & = & E \left[ \sum_{i = 1}^y X_i \right]\\
  & = & yE \left[ X_i \right]
\end{eqnarray*}
This allows to compute $E[Z]$
\begin{eqnarray*}
  E \left[ Z \right] & = & E_Y \left[ E \left[ Z|Y = y \right] \right]\\
  & = & E_Y \left[ yE \left[ X_i \right] \right]\\
  & = & E \left[ Y \right] E \left[ X_i \right]
\end{eqnarray*}

For the variance of $Z$, you could exploit formulas for conditional variances (such as [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_variance)).

You could apply a similar argument in order to derive the cumulative distribution of $Z$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \Pr \left[ Z \leqslant z \right] & = & E_Y \left[ \Pr \left[ Z \leqslant z|y
  \right] \right]
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: @lip1 Sorry, there were two terms missing from the formula.